# bq M10: keyboard problems with Firefox

Tags: keyboard, firefox, ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

On the bq Aquaris M10, with Ubuntu Touch OTA10.1, I frequently encounter problems with Firefox. In particular, keyboard input from a Bluetooth keyboard randomly doesn't work anymore until I close and reopen Firefox.

Comment: I've also seen this as far as I can tell it's an Xmir issue as top is telling me it's using 99% CPU

Comment: Ok, I'll try to check next time it happens to see if I get the same CPU usage.